# Having some issues with re.sub

Tags: python, regex

In my program I'm parsing Japanese definitions, and I need to take a few things out. There are three things I need to take things out between. `「text」` `(text)` `《text》`

To take out things between `「」` I've been doing `sentence = re.sub('「[^)]*」','', sentence)` The problem with this is, for some reason if there are parentheses within `「」` it will not replace anything. Also, I've tried using the same code for the other two things like `sentence = re.sub('([^)]*)','', sentence)`
`sentence = re.sub('《[^)]*》','', sentence)` but it doesn't work for some reason. There isn't an error or anything, it just doesn't replace anything.

How can I make this work, or is  there some better way of doing this?

**EDIT:**

I'm having a slight problem with another part of this though. Before I replace anything I check the length to make sure it's over a certain length.

```
parse = re.findall(r'「[^」]*」','', match.text)
if len(str(parse)) > 8:
    sentence = re.sub(r'「[^」]*」','', match.text)
```

This seems to be causing an error now:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Dominic/PycharmProjects/untitled9/main.py", line 48, in <module>
    parse = re.findall(r'「[^」]*」','', match.text)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 206, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\re.py", line 275, in _compile
    bypass_cache = flags & DEBUG
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'
```

I sort of understand what's causing this, but I don't understand why It's not working just from that slight change. I know the re.sub part is fine, It's just the first two lines that are causing the problems.

Comment: Your regexp matches anything between the angles that is not a parenthesis, so no wonder. You need `sentence = re.sub('「[^」]*」','', sentence)`

Comment: Regarding the error in your edit: `re.findall` does not take a replacement string. Therefore the `match.text` gets passed on as `flags` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You should read a tutorial on regular expressions so you understand what your regexps do.

The regexp `'「[^)]*」'` matches anything between the angles that is not a closing parenthesis. You need this:

```
sentence = re.sub(r'「[^」]*」','', sentence)
```

The second regexp has an additional problem: Parentheses have a special meaning (when they are *not* inside square brackets), so to match parentheses you need to write `\(` and `\)`. So you need this:

```
'\([^)]*\)'
```

Finally: You should always use raw strings for your python regexps. It doesn't happen to make a difference in this case, but it very often does, and the bugs are maddening to spot. E.g., use:

```
r'\([^)]*\)'
```

Comment: Specifically, it matches anything that isn't a *closing* parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = re.sub(ur'「[^」]*」','', sentence)

                       ^^
```

You need to change the `negatiion based quantifer` to stop at `」` instead of `)`.

You should use `unicode` flag if dealing with them.If there are `)` within them then it will fail as you have used `「[^)]*」`

```
                ^^
```

You have instructed regex to stop when it finds `)`.